# Conditionally remove order details section in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, orders

I want to remove the order details table in WooCommerce in my functions.php if a if statement is true. I've searched a lot but don't know how to do this.

This is how the file is included in WooCommerce wc-template-functions.php:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_order_details_table' ) ) {

    /**
     * Displays order details in a table.
     *
     * @param mixed $order_id Order ID.
     */
    function woocommerce_order_details_table( $order_id ) {
        if ( ! $order_id ) {
            return;
        }

        wc_get_template( 'order/order-details.php', array(
            'order_id' => $order_id,
        ) );
    }
}
```

So I need something like this:

```
if ( value != true ) {
    hide_order_details();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated** *(Optionally showing customer details)*

You can simply use the following hooked function *(that has the `$order_id` as available argument)* with your condition in an if statement *(where you will define `$value`)*

The following will remove the order details table in My account > View order:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_view_order', 'custom_action_view_order', 5, 1 );
function custom_action_view_order( $order_id ){
    $value = false;

    if( ! $value ){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_view_order', 'woocommerce_order_details_table', 10 );

        ## ----- Optionally show customer details (if needed) ----- ##

        if ( ! $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ) ) {
            return;
        }

        if( is_user_logged_in() ){
            wc_get_template( 'order/order-details-customer.php', array( 'order' => $order ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**1) With customer details:**

[image]

**2) Without customer details:**

[image]

Comment: Nice one! But it also removes the billing/shipping details. I don't know if it's op objective. Still nice answer.

Comment: Is it possible to replace the content with an other php file? So instead of the order details set an other php with include?

Comment: You can use the Loic code to remove the table (and shipping/billing details). You can then add a new method on the `woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table` action that can output content after the table in the `order-detail` template. Take care as `woocommerce_view_order` action is also called on `order/tracking.php` template.

Comment: @Mtxz How should woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table work when I've removed the order-details before? Sounds not logic to me.

Comment: @Johnny97 you're right I just tested it. This will prevent being able to use the `woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table` hook. Loic edited his answer about adding customer details. I think you could be able to add your custom content using the same approach.

Comment: @Mtxz Updated (with or without customer details)…

Comment: @Johnny97 Yes you can include any other template or custom template or php file… but this is another question / answer.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, there is no hook you can use in the template.

But you can easily override the `order/order-details.php` template in your theme to add a condition on whether to output the detail table or not.

The concerned template is in `woocommerce/templates/order/order-details.php`. You can copy it to `your-theme/woocommerce/templates/order/order-details.php` and make the required change.

This way, you don't edit original Woocommerce files and use the right way to override woocommerce outputs. Check the `order-details` template yourself, you'll see there is no hook here permitting to prevent outputting the table. But a simple `if` wrapper with your condition around the `<table>` code should do the trick.

Edit: it seems that the filter `woocommerce_order_item_visible` used in `order-details-item.php` template can help you to prevent displaying some lines in the order details table. But the template is called within the order detail table html, so you cannot fully remove the table using it.

Note: I'm not sure if this template part is used somewhere else. If it's the case, you should add to your display condition to check if the actual page is the one you want to apply changes on (customer dashboard order detail). If the template is used somewhere else, It'll apply your changes in every places this template is used.

Comment: Please read my question. I don't need this in my checkout form hook. I need to remove it from the view-order page if my var is true

Comment: Ah yes I mis-read. You're talking about the page to view order detail from customer dash right ?

Comment: Edited my answer, sorry for the first one

Comment: I'll try this. Im using the Divi theme so not sure if overwriting is possible :/

Comment: It should work. Woocommerce will look in your theme files hierarchy to select an override template file, and if not exist, use the default one from its plugin folder. I just tested on a random theme, and I can remove the table from the overridden `order-details` template in my theme.